# How can I execute a global Apex class from the Anonymous Apex window?

Tags: apex, class, execute-anonymous

Hi I have a managed package installed in an org with several global classes. Which are documented as the following:

Apex class - global with sharing class FeatureConsoleService

Method of Class - global static namespace.FeatureConsoleService.ActivationResponse enable(Id recordId)

How would I call/execute this method from the anonymous Apex window?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try as below namespace.classname.methodname(); If any input parameters there you have to add parameters as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following syntax for invoking a method that is defined in a managed package.

```
namespace_prefix.class.method(args)
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_namespace_prefix.htm